# jQuery - get classes of each li as an array

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have 10 different menu items, all of them have different colored borders, like this:

```
<ul id="flipbox" class="main-menu" align="right">
 <li class="item cyan active"><a href="#" alt="" title="">item 1</a></li>
 <li class="item orange"><a href="#" alt="" title="">item 2</a></li>
 <li class="item yellow"><a href="#" alt="" title="">item 3</a></li>
 <li class="item brown"><a href="#" alt="" title="">item 4</a></li>
 <li class="item blue"><a href="#" alt="" title="">item 5</a></li>
 <li class="item pink"><a href="#" alt="" title="">item 6</a></li>
 <li class="item green "><a href="#" alt="" title="">item 7</a></li>
 <li class="item sand"><a href="#" alt="" title="">item 8</a></li>
 <li class="item darkgray"><a href="#" alt="" title="">item 9</a></li>
</ul>
```

Notice the first li, with class 'active'. Through jQuery, I would like to change the bgcolor of the active li, to a color that is used for its border. Is such a thing possible possible? For now, I came up with this code, but it appears to be buggy. I haven't gotten to the second part of this task yet (get the color and apply it).

```
// Current menu item function
$(document).ready(function(){

// Array with li classes 
var menuItems = [];
$(".main-menu li").each(function() { menuItems.push($(this).attr('class').split(' ')) });
for (n = 0; n < 9; n++) {
    for (m = 0; m < 3; m++)
    if (menuItems[n] ===  'active' ) {
        alert('.' + menuItems[n][m]);
    }
}
});
```

Comment: what is the question ?

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on that? What are you trying to achieve with the `menuItems` array?

Comment: If `menuItems` is a 2D array, an item will never equal `active`

Comment: Yes, I was missing the 'y-coordinate' 

    menuItems[n][m] ===  'active'

Comment: Also, if you have 10 items then it should be `for (n = 0; n < 10; n++)`. Or better still, calculate the length first: `$(".main-menu li").length'

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot equal sign and/or use 10. It's been a while since I last used loops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this isn't jQuery, sorry, but if you want to style list items with an active class, then use css:

```
li.cyan {
    background-color: cyan;
}
li.cyan.active {
    background-color: somethingelse;
}
```

EDIT:

In jQuery, to change all active list items' background colour to its border colour:

```
$(".main-menu li.active").each(function() {
    var borderColor = $(this).css('border-color');
    $(this).css('background-color', borderColor);
});
```

Comment: Yes, but that's another 10 classes. I don't mind, just wanted to see if I could do it with jQuery.

Comment: I think even if you did it in jQuery, at some point you would have to define the individual border/background colours for each element. All jQuery would do is change the style manually, so defining it in CSS is much simpler. Also, depending on the colour you want the active elements to change to, there could be something more compact you can do in CSS.

Comment: Can't jQuery 'read' the CSS value and assign it to another property?

Comment: I think jQuery would only be able to read the style value if it's inline, not if it's defined in an external css file.

Comment: Hey, I may be wrong. Why do you want to read the css property of an object to add to another? If the active list items all get set to the same colour, then that's easy to do in CSS.

Comment: I was wrong, jquery works out the computed style, I shall edit my answer with a possible solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```
$(".main-menu li").css('background-color', null)
    .filter('.active').css('background-color', function () { 
         var classes = $(this).attr('class').split(/\s+/);
         for (var i = 0; i < classes.length; i++) {
             if (classes[i] !== 'item' && classes[i] !== 'active')
                  return classes[i];
         }
        return 'none';
     });
```

[<kbd>jsFiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/89ndJ/)